# Unable to install matplotlib on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

I am struggling to install matplotlib 1.2.1 on Mountain lion.
I am NOT using homebrew or easy install. I am compiling using python setup.py build and install. 
If I try and use homebrew I get errors or told that apple distributes freetype is OS X and that I may need to call ENV.x11 in the formula install.

I am working in a tcsh shell.

```
basedirlist is: ['/usr/local/', '/usr', '/usr/X11', '/opt/local']
============================================================================
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB


    matplotlib: 1.2.1
                python: 2.7.2 (default, Feb 25 2012, 19:26:57)  [GCC 4.2.1
                        (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
              platform: darwin

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: 1.8.0.dev-928289b
             freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
               Tkinter: Tkinter: version not identified, Tk: 8.6, Tcl: 8.6
                  Gtk+: no
                        * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                        * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
       Mac OS X native: yes
                    Qt: no
                   Qt4: no
                PySide: no
                 Cairo: no

OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
              dateutil: 1.5
                  pytz: 2013b

OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: 9.02
                 latex: no

[Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
============================================================================
pymods ['pylab']
packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay']
running install
running build
running build_py
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data
running build_ext
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_928289b_20130808-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/X11/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_928289b_20130808-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/X11/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I./freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/src/ft2font.o
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
src/ft2font.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
src/ft2font.cpp:854:   instantiated from here
src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/vv/86b4jvnx07559plzpbz14t600000gq/T//ccFs3Oce.out (No such file or directory)
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I want to install everything using just python setup.py build and install as I need specific versions of freetype2 and libpng. I am sure that I have freetype2 installed properly already and libpng-1.5.11. I need to use libpng-1.5.11 as a programme that has been written needs that one.

How can I get it to recognise where these are?